# php str_replace returns zero value

Tags: php, str-replace, file-put-contents

I want to add some lines to many css files in different folders. everything is ok. but str_replace function returns zero value when write is with file_put_contents. This is my code:

```
$from = '@media (max-width: 767px) {';
$to = '.st'.$folder.' {}'. PHP_EOL .'.sb'.$folder.' {}'. PHP_EOL .'@media (max-width: 767px) {';
$item_content = str_replace($from, $to, $item_content);
```

Any idea?
Thank you

Comment: at least, `$from = '@media \(max-width: 767px\) {';`

Comment: If nothing was written to the file, how were you sure everything is ok?

Comment: We don't know the initial value of `$item_content`, if it's empty in the first place, the result will be an empty string again ;)